# Left continuous function which agrees with continuous function almost everywhere agrees everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we are working on $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure, and we have two functions $f$ and $g$, where $f$ is left continuous everywhere and $g$ is continuous everywhere. If we know they agree almost everywhere, can we say that they agree everywhere too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ has measure $0$ then $E^{c}$ is dense. This is because if $E^{c}$ is not dense then there would be an interval $(a,b)$ containing no point of $E^{c}$. This means $(a,b) \subset E$, contradicting the fact that $E$ has measure $0$. Using this it follows that the two functions are equal on dense set. Given any $x$ and any $n \geq 1$ there must be some point $x_n$ in $(x-\frac 1 n ,x)$ in this dense set. The two functions are equal to $x_n$ for each $n$. Now take limit as $ n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

**Hint:** You need to show for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(a)=g(a)$. Show that in the interval $[a-1/n,a)$ you can find an $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$. Take limits.